# starting multiprocessing within thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing

## python 3.6, anaconda, opengl library glumpy

I am creating a physics simulation.
Is there a way to achieve below?

Drawing part is fine, I am using an opengl library called glumpy and it draws repeatedly given fps. Update part has a little cpu intensive for loop which I want to use multiprocessing.

So what I thought was to have a thread for lower branch so that update function is fired every set time separate from the upper draw branch. And another multiprocessing for the cpu intense calculation in update function.

[image: Basically what I want to do]

Series coding where update is called within draw function so that update happens every draw frame has worked, but it is just too slow.

Thank you. Please let me know if my descriptions are poor. Will try to improve.

Comment: Do you want to know that which library provide multiprocessing? You can implement your model by using multiprocessing library.

Comment: @goodahn sorry that I caused confusion. I want to do above with the multiprocessing library but I simply couldn't find an example or how to do it. When I tried what seemed right was that multiprocessing part 2 did not return when seemingly the calculation was finished. Basically I don't know what went wrong and would like a concise example.

Comment: Are you using global variables? Then, how about using shared memory? If you use numpy, I recommend [SharedArray library](https://pypi.org/project/SharedArray/)